# Which machine learning model would be feasible for stripping the background from product photos?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

My goal is to be able to have a way to process a product photo through the model, and have it return the same photo with the product against a white background. The product photos will be of varying sizes and product types.

I'd like to feed the model photos of products with backgrounds, and those without. In the future I will also expand on the dataset with partially removed backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an easy way of doing this, I'd suggest the K-means clustering algorithm. Assuming that you have a simple plain background and an image (of interest) you can obtain the RGB pixel values and use a K-means clustering algorithm with the number of clusters set to 2.

Let me explain this to you with the help of an example. Suppose you have an image of dimension 28*28 (just another arbitrary dimension). The total number of pixels in the image would be 784. Each pixel is represented as a combination of 3 RGB values ranging from 0-255.

A K-Means clustering algorithm will cluster the pixel values into K clusters thus each cluster represents pixel values which are more similar than the pixel values in another cluster. This technique is especially helpful in drawing contours (borders) around images of interest.

In the K-means clustering algorithm, there would be 784 sample points each represented in a 3 dimensional plane for this example. It will cluster these data points into K (2 in this example) clusters.

Here is a very simple implementation of the [K-means clustering algorithm](https://github.com/skymanaditya1/Machine_Learning/blob/master/K-Means_Cluster/kmeans.java).

If you are looking for advanced machine learning implementation, then I'd suggest you look for Deep Convolution Neural Networks for Background Removal in Images. This machine learning technique has been successfully used for the task for background image removal

Read more about it from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/denoising-dirty-documents/forums/t/16298/background-removal-deep-convolutional-networks-1-232), [here](https://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/195180/1/Braham2016Deep.pdf) and [here](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~slazebni/spring14/lec24_cnn.pdf).